# Does mongos do connection pooling?

Tags: mongodb

Im going to invoke tens and thousands of lambda functions for microprocessing. The whole process will take just 10 seconds to complete. The issue we are facing is, 1 invoke =1 connection, then close. I can't do much processing in one invocation.

So we are looking for some connection poolers in between lambda and MongoDB servers. I know the drivers can have, but unfortunately, one invoke can do one job only.

We are thinking of putting Mongos in between(but its a single node MongoDB), will it work? If yes what parameter can use to setup the pooling?

Comment: See https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/administration/connection-pool-overview/